# PDO extension not loading in PHP

Tags: php, pdo, php-extension

So i'm trying to use the PDO module in PHP on a Redhat based distribution (RHEL7) to interact with a database.

In my Php script i have the '**use PDO;**' directive, but in the PHP log i get an error : **PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PDO' not found in ...**

The extension is uncommented in the php.ini file (**extension = pdo.so**), i have tried with the relative and the absolute path. I even reinstalled the php-pdo package (*yum install*), but without success.

I've compared my phpinfo() with a working phpinfo(), and i am missing the **PDO** section.

I have checked and Apache loads the correct php.ini file

I've passed all my extensions permissions to **755** just to be sure.

I don't get any php warning at startup so i don't know where the problem seems to be.

Comment: did you restart the apache/php-fpm server after installing it?

Comment: Yes, each time i change anything in my php.ini file i restart my apache server

Comment: Put `phpinfo();` inside your script and provide output

Comment: When I run phpinfo, I see these options for pdo in the configure command section: '--with-pdo-dblib=/usr/local/opt/freetds' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-pdo-odbc=unixODBC,/usr/local/opt/unixodbc' '--with-pdo-pgsql=/usr/local/opt/libpq' '--with-pdo-sqlite=/usr/local/opt/sqlite' If you don't see something similar to this, try installing the php-mysql package.

Comment: '--enable-pdo=shared' '--with-pgsql=shared,/usr/pgsql-9.6' '--with-pdo-pgsql=shared,/usr/pgsql-9.6' '--enable-mysqlnd=shared' '--with-mysqli=shared,mysqlnd' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared,mysqlnd' '--with-oci8=shared,/logiciels/php/7.1.4/lib/oic' '--with-pdo-oci=shared,/logiciels/php/7.1.4/lib/oic' '--with-sqlite3=shared' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared,/usr'

Comment: You mentioned that you dont see the PDO, pdo_dblib, pdo_mysql, PDO_ODBC, pdo_pgsql, pdo_sqlite sections. If this is still the case, try re-installing the php-mysql package using the force option.

Comment: Juste tried re-installing the php-mysql package, but stil got the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error : 
First i started using php in direct command line, and set the env' variable `LD_DEBUG=libs`:

```
./php -c /path/to/php.ini /path/to/php/file.php
```

So with that i was able to get the debug on the dynamic loading of my modules and on the php.ini.

I saw that there was an uncommented line that was blocking the loading of the modules in the INI file, then you have to load the mysql.so module before the pdo_mysql.so and of course restart you apache server.